# How does the system define the portion of virtual memory a process gets?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, virtual-memory

If there is a 32 bit system (assume Windows), the virtual address space is 4GB. So CPu can generate any address between this range. Then shoudn't a process also be able to address anywhere in this range?
It is said that each process has its own private virtual address space.Then How does the system facilitate this?

In other words the CPU generates a 32 bit address, and that gets translated into physical address. Now how does CPU know that a specific process has to address only a specific part of the virtual address space(its private virtual address space).

Suppose a process addresses an address out of its private virtual address space, what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A program has to call `VirtualAlloc()` on Windows to tell the operating system that it wants to use a chunk of virtual memory.  Often called indirectly as a result of allocating memory from a heap or loading a DLL.

The operating system, in turn, sets up the page mapping tables that the CPU uses to translate a virtual address as used in the program to a physical RAM address as output on its address bus pins.  One of three unusual things can happen whenever the CPU reads or writes data or executes code at a virtual memory address:

- if there is no entry in the page mapping tables then the CPU raises a general protection fault trap.  The operating system verifies that the address is invalid and terminates the program
- if the page is not mapped to RAM yet then the CPU raises a page fault trap.  The operating system finds a page of RAM that's unused, swapping out a used page if necessary.  And ensures the content is valid, loading it from a file or the paging file if necessary.  And updates the table entry so it now has the physical address of the RAM page.  Execution resumes as normal
- the CPU verifies that access to the page is allowed.  A write to a page that is marked as read-only or an execute of a instruction in the page that's marked as no-execute generates a general protection fault trap.  The operating system terminates the program.

Every process has its own set of page mapping tables, ensuring that one process cannot access the RAM pages that are used by another.  Unless sharing is specifically requested, common for pages of code loaded from an executable file and memory mapped files.  A context switch loads the CR2 register, the CPU register that contains the address of the page mapping table.

So there is no scenario where a process can ever address memory outside of its private virtual address space, the lack of a matching paging table entry ensures that this terminates the program.

Answer (score 0):

The whole 4 GB address space is available to the process (although typically the upper half is reserved for kernel data), and the MMU maps parts of it to physical memory. The process cannot go "out" of its address space (all the 4 GB of it are allowed to be used), but if some part of it hasn't been mapped to physical memory a hardware exception is raised.

The address space is said to be private since the operating system changes the settings of the MMU at task switch, so every process sees a different independent memory layout (although parts of the address space can be shared with other processes).

Comment: what sort of settings are changed at task switch?

Comment: Most importantly for what we are discussing now, the virtual -> physical memory mappings and the memory pages protection flags.